# Error from OdbcDataAdapter.Fill

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, database-connection, dataadapter

I sometimes get two different of error when executing  OdbcDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable). 
Here is the code example:

```
string odbc = "select item, upcno from table";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(odbc, fconn);
OdbcDataAdapter oda = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
oda.Fill(dt);
```

1. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2. System.InvalidOperationException: No data exists for the row/column.

Does anyone have clue to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is that the real SQL or a demo?  Because those names are questionable.  `Table` is a reserved word, for instance.

Comment: well, this is a real SQL, I just remved the table name

Comment: Are you instantiating `dt` first, such as:  `DataTable dt = new DataTable();`?

Comment: @user2460647 have you try my answer, are you still get above exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you get connection object from your question but you can do as below. don't create class level connections, you can create it when you want and properly dispose it at the end.

```
public DataTable GetDataTableFromAdapter(string queryString)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (OdbcConnection connection =
                new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter =
                new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Call it as

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromAdapter("select [item], [upcno] from [table]");
```

Comment: I'm testing your suggestions, and it looks better now. let see how it goes